4x4 Outdoor Bench Swing
Would a 4x4x10 beam with a 4x4 joist handle a bench swing/hammock chair? It's already anchored to the ground with 2ft of cement.

How are the two pieces connected and supported and how and where is the chair attached? What is anchored to the ground?    A diagram would help.

A beam and a joist? Your description is confusing. You also didn't mention span, which is critical. Please revise to be more clear, and take the [tour].

Handle? Yes. Handle well? No. Too much flexing.
I had tried to re-use a 4x4 for an A-frame swing and ended up replacing the top beam with a 4x6 (with the 6" being vertical); 4x4 legs were fine. Even with light loads (children), it flexed too much. I didn't think it would break, but the flexing kind of ruined the experience.

Is there a way for me to strengthen it without changing the 4x4 post? Strengthen with another 4x4?

Or a 2x4 as a brace with a screw on 4 points of the post?

The A-frame swing I built for my kids has a 4x6 top beam, and it still flexes a lot! But a bench swing does not attach to the center of the beam, but closer to the ends, so I image it would flex less.

It's probably not the posts, @Jon, that are the problem. It's the 4x4 as your top beam. That's the one that should be a 4x6
